# Android Camera Preview Live Filter | Surface View

Tags: android, image-processing, filter, camera, surfaceview

I am implementing Surface View based Camera App, the app is working absolutely fine, the app has one more requirement, which is show the Preview in Black & White and capture that black and white image. I just want to ask how to make the preview in Black and white? Steps with short description would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code ..

Comment: I have used the API Doc following code :
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

I just need to know what changes should i made before calling mCamera.StartPreview(); to show the black and white preview.

Comment: One approach is demonstrated in "Show + capture camera" in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).  Various filters are available.  In the current implementation the shader is only applied to the preview, and it records video rather than stills (and doesn't apply the filter to the recording).  But you could use that for the preview and then capture stills in YUV, and clear U/V to get B&W.

Answer (score -1):

you can make the parameter of camera, and then apply colorfilter to the parameter to get the different effect, but first you have to check the supported colorfilter for your device, basically it is device dependent.

Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

```
        camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters(); //this will provide the supporting parameter for your device.
         p.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);  //it will set the flash mode.
         p.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);  //it will set the color effect to the preview and recording videos.


        camera.setParameters(p);
```

but be careful with nexus device , i had checked this method into nexus 5, the camera preview was showing with effect, but recording was done as normal.

check it out, hope it will help.